# Two activities in same Layout?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

it seems like stupid and beginner question. But can I have two activities in same layout?

So my `main.xml` layout is like this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <MapView>
    <ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have a `MapActivity` class that is already too long. So I planned to make a new `ListActivity` class that handles the `ListView` content.

I heard we can use `Fragment` but after reading the docs, it seems it is used for handling two layouts in same activity. Opposite of what I need.

Thanks

Comment: this is what `Fragments` are for

Comment: Which method to use to separate the code? Can you give me a link? THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can't have multiple Activity* to run parallely. You can use `MapActivity` with `ListView` as a content control.

```
public class MapList extends MapActivity {

ListView mListView;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.layoutfile);
        mListView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listviewid);
    }
}
```

*note: one can take multiple ListView control in same Activity.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But both the code that handles Map and List are long. If possible I want to separate it. Is there any way? **EDIT** So it is not possible. Thanks

Comment: @DarcCode Look at the comment by thepoosh. You can create these using fragments and embed them in your activity. This will allow you to separate the code.

Comment: @user1420101 Can fragment do that? which method is used to the activities?

Comment: @DarcCode Please refer to the fragment documentation in developer.android.com. Also, there is no MapFragment at this point (you will probably need to host a ListFragment in a MapActivity). Then look at the FragmentManager Documentation on how to load the fragment. The fragment will have it's independant code. Hope this helps...

Comment: @DarcCode [this](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps) is what you need

Comment: @user1420101 Thanks, I never knew we could do this. @ hotveryspicy looks complicated, but I will try. Thanks